# Developing a MIDlet for Windows Mobile

Tags: java, windows-mobile, midlet, midp

Is it possible to create a MIDP Application for Windows Mobile?

In other words, I want to create a MIDlet and run it on a Windows Mobile Simulator(any).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by default, as Windows Mobile itself does not include a MIDP Java runtime environment.

Most mobile phone [OEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OEM) will include such an environment in the phones they sell, like [Samsung](http://www.samsungmobile.com) did with [JBlend](http://www.aplix.co.jp/) v4.0.0 in my [Omnia Qwerty](http://www.samsungmobile.nl/mobiele-telefoons/samsung-omnia-qwerty-b7610).

To be able to run development MIDlet on the Windows Mobile Simulator you need to get and deploy such a runtime environment to it yourself. According to [answer by slyfox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416189/developing-a-midlet-for-windows-mobile/2416229#2416229) Sun itself provides such a runtime environment for Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 2):

The [Java ME 3.0 SDK](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30.jsp#1) supports Windows Mobile.

> The new Java ME Platform SDK architecture allows integration of 3rd party emulators and devices. Java ME Platform SDK comes with Sun's Java runtime environment for Windows Mobile. A user can install this runtime on a Windows Mobile device or a Microsoft device emulator and experience all the on-device features of Java ME Platform SDK.